# JivyMD scrollbar for multiple cells in gridview layout doesnt work

Tags: python, gridview

I want to create a gridview layout in which there are 10 cells; however, I am having difficulties displaying all 10 cells with a fixed height (the width will be adjusted based on the window size), and it seems impossible to fit all 10 cells on one screen. That's why I want to use scrollbars. so the size of each cell will be maintained. and at least on the screen will be displaying only 4 cells.

below is my coding and output :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDFloatingActionButton
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    background_color = [0.678, 0.847, 0.902, 1]  # Light blue color
    spacing = 50

class MyGridCell(MDRectangleFlatButton):
    def __init__(self, cell_data, **kwargs):
        super(MyGridCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = cell_data['name']

class MyGridLayout(MDGridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.padding = [200, 0]
        self.cols = 2
        self.spacing = 10

    def on_padding(self, instance, value):
        self.update_padding()

    def update_padding(self):
        self.padding_left = self.padding[0]
        self.padding_right = self.padding[0]

    def create_widgets(self):
        cell_data_list = [
            {'name': 'Cell 1', 'purpose': 'Purpose 1'},
            {'name': 'Cell 2', 'purpose': 'Purpose 2'},
            {'name': 'Cell 3', 'purpose': 'Purpose 1'},
            {'name': 'Cell 4', 'purpose': 'Purpose 2'},
            # Add more dictionaries for additional cells
        ]
        
        for cell_data in cell_data_list:
            button = MyGridCell(cell_data=cell_data)
            self.add_widget(button)

    def adjust_cell_sizes(self):
        for child in self.children:
            child.size_hint = (1, 1)


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Window.maximize()  # Maximize the window
        main_layout = MyBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        header_layout = MyBoxLayout(size_hint=(1, None), height=70, padding=10, spacing=800)
        logo_image = Image(source='LogoFull.png', size_hint=(None, 1), width=200)
        search_layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint=(None, 1))
        search_input = MDTextField(hint_text='Search..', size_hint=(None, None), width=300, height=30)
        search_icon = MDFloatingActionButton(icon='magnify')

        search_layout.add_widget(search_input)
        search_layout.add_widget(search_icon)
        header_layout.add_widget(logo_image)
        header_layout.add_widget(search_layout)

        footer_layout = MyBoxLayout(size_hint=(1, None), height=50)
        footer_label = Label(text='Footer')

        scrollview = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False)
        layout = MyGridLayout()
        layout.create_widgets()
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)
        main_layout.add_widget(header_layout)
        main_layout.add_widget(scrollview)
        main_layout.add_widget(footer_layout)

        # Bind the pos and size properties of the layouts to update the background rectangles
        header_layout.bind(pos=self.update_header_background, size=self.update_header_background)
        footer_layout.bind(pos=self.update_footer_background, size=self.update_footer_background)

        return main_layout

    def update_header_background(self, instance, value):
        instance.canvas.before.clear()
        with instance.canvas.before:
            Color(*instance.background_color)
            Rectangle(pos=instance.pos, size=instance.size)

    def update_footer_background(self, instance, value):
        instance.canvas.before.clear()
        with instance.canvas.before:
            Color(*instance.background_color)
            Rectangle(pos=instance.pos, size=instance.size)

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.children[1].children[0].adjust_cell_sizes()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS5pr.png)

what i try:

1. I tried to add scrollbars. but the cells won't move when I try to scroll them.
2. I also try to add more cells, but the height of the cells is reduced.
3. i try to set the height of the cells but it doesn't seems responsive to that coding